# How to return back to the homepage with the shell tab from another page not present in the shell (Xamarin.Forms Android-iOS)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, navigation, tabbar

Sorry for the title since it's unclear.

Right now, I have an homepage that has two ImageButtons (which are not present in the shell xaml). I want the home button of the shell to go back to the homepage. [Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IplGx.png)

This is my current AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibManager.Views"
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
       x:Class="LibManager.AppShell">
    <TabBar>
        <Tab x:Name="homebtn" Title="Home" Icon="home_24">
            <ShellContent Route="HomePage">
                <local:HomePage/>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Cerca" Icon="search_24">
                <ShellContent>
                    <local:SearchPage/>
                </ShellContent>
            </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

This is how I open the other two pages:

```
private async void userOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("userpage");
}
```

```
private async void bellOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("notificationspage");
}
```

When I try to go back to the homepage by clicking on the home button nothing happens. Even if I switch to search and turn back to home it will show me the previous page. [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7mRk.png)

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to go back to the homepage by clicking on the home button nothing happens. Even if I switch to search and turn back to home it will show me the previous page.

It can't go back to the homepage by the bottom tab button. You can do it by  (virtual) back button(remove Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False") or [right swipe gesture](https://imgur.com/a/PSuvDA2).

Comment: Is there another way to make it possible? Like making two tabs with these two pages not visible in the shell?

Comment: Unfortunately no.